# more concise way to describe a system that is doomed to fail, inherently flawed, temporary/transient

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions

I'm trying to describe, in one or two words, a system which is set up so that it cannot be long lasting; it is destined to collapse.

"Marx and Engels finish their overview of Marxist theory by arguing that the very nature of the bourgeoisie system makes it..."

I was going to use Sisyphean but that refers to a task that can never be finished rather than one that will end in disaster.

edit: currently using 'sisyphean and transient'

edit: the word doomed doesn't fit the sentence.

edit: to make it clear: im trying to find the word that best fits the sentence, im trying to convey the idea that the system cannot last, it is inherently self-destructive and will end sooner rather than later

Comment: You just provided a whole bunch of wordings yourself that all fit your criteria: "not long lasting", "destined to collapse", "doomed to fail". So. What else is it that you need?

Comment: @RegDwigнt, OP's asking for one word.  The OP used phrases to describe that word but they are not a single word.

Comment: yes but none of those phrases convey the full idea, they are like pieces of a jigsaw, im looking for the word that is the picture on the box. i am constrained on space otherwise i would spent a full paragraph explaining what i mean.

Comment: The system is "unstable".

Comment: Not sure why this question is still closed, but here's another option: *unworkable*.

Answer (score 4):

It's simply [**doomed**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/doomed):

> a :  destiny; especially :  unhappy destiny
>   b :  death, ruin

For example: *their marriage is doomed from the start*.

Comment: But OP uses this word.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes; my point is that *doomed* is a single-word synonym for the phrase *doomed to fail*.

Comment: And my point is that '[On ELU,] we write stuff in comments that is too obvious to qualify for an answer. ' As Reg Dwight has said.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "Too obvious" sounds a bit subjective; I suspect many people who use "doomed to fail" don't realize that "doomed" by itself is a synonym that meets the OP's requirement for "one or two words."  If I'm wrong, it seems like downvoting is the proper response.

Comment: yes but " the very nature of the bourgeoisie system makes it doomed" does not quite sound right, nor does it convey the full idea of what i am trying to say.

Comment: There is the sister site, ELL, for more basic questions. Would you consider a question answerable by one being able to check a dictionary for 'doomed' as well as 'doomed to fail' suitable for a site intended for 'linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts'?

Comment: (For one thing, it's not *bourgeoisie system*. It's *bourgeois system* - or *capitalist system* or *capitalism*.)

Answer (score 1):

Consider, ***inviable***, ***unviable***, and [*non-viable*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inviable%2Cunviable%2Cnon-viable&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=4&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinviable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunviable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnon%20-%20viable%3B%2Cc0).

> inviable: not [viable](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/viable#viable__2) [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/inviable)
>
> unviable: not capable of working successfully; not feasible [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/pt/defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o/ingl%C3%AAs-americano/unviable)